# Show actual Image instead of ObjectId with MonogoDB's Normalized Data Model

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I want to display a picture which was uploaded to the MongoDB 
Currently it displays the ObjectId

[image]

**Templates.coffee**

```js
Template.projectShow.helpers
  projects: ->
    Projects.find()
```

**Projects.html**

```
<template name="projectShow">
  <h2>Projects</h2>
     {{#each projects}}
        {{> showTemplate}}
     {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="showTemplate">  
  Title : {{title}} <br>
  Image : {{projectImage}}
</template>
```

**Collections.coffee**

```
@Projects = new Meteor.Collection('projects')
@imageStore = new FS.Store.GridFS("project-images")
@Images = new FS.Collection("project-images", stores: [imageStore])

Schemas.Projects = new SimpleSchema
  title:
    type: String

  projectImage:
    type: String
    autoform:
      afFieldInput:
      type: "fileUpload"
      collection: "Images"

Projects.attachSchema(Schemas.Projects)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create a helper function for the showTemplate template that looks up the data you need in the file collection

projectImage returns the id of that image stored in the collectionsfs collection. So to get the actual image url, you'll have to do something along the lines of this: (might not be 100% correct syntax, but just to explain the flow)

```js
Template.showTemplate.helpers({
    projectImage: function(){
        return Images.findOne({_id: Template.instance().data.projectImage}).url();
    }
});
```

Comment: I think you meant url()